# Color or content of quotes not showing

Tags: random, colors, quote

I wrote two functions for changing the color of the background randomly and the content of the quotes also. Next I made a button to perform these functions when clicked.
 I succeeded in changing the color but the quotes won't appear and when both of the functions are on the program the color won't change too. 
 What is wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>




<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- let's get started -->
<title>Random Quote</title>

<!-- //******CSS********************// -->
<style>
   .Container{
   height:100%;

   display:grid;

   background-color:white;
   }   
</style>
<!-- //******JavaScript************// -->
<script>
function randColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    if(color=="#000000"){ // to exclude white from brower background color since the color of the 'Container' is always white    
    color[2]=color[2]+1;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;}   
    else
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;    
}

function randQuote(){
    var randNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*10) ;
    var quote=[
    "You can do anything, but not everything. —David Allen",
    "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.—Antoine de Saint-Exupéry",
    "The richest man is not he who has the most,but he who needs the least. —Unknown Author",
    "You miss 100 percent of the shots you never take. —Wayne Gretzky",
    "You must be the change you wish to see in the world. —Gandhi",
    "We are what we repeatedly do. excellence, then, is not an act but a habit.—Aristotle"
    "A wise man gets more use from his enemies than a fool from his friends.—Baltasar Gracian", 
    "What we think, or what we know, or what we believe is, in the end, of little consequence. The only consequence is what we do.—John Ruskin",
    "The real voyage of discovery consists not in seeking new lands but seeing with new eyes.—Marcel Proust",
    "Don\’t ever wrestle with a pig. You’ll both get dirty, but the pig will enjoy it.—Cale Yarborough"
    ];

    document.getElementById("ShowQuote").innerHTML=quote[randNum];
}

</script>
</head>

<!-- //******HTML******************// -->
<body>

<div class="Container">
     <div id="ShowQuote">

     </div> 

     <button class="btn" onclick="randQuote();randColor()">New Quote</button>





</div>

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Run your HTML through the validator and fix your errors first.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it but still don't know how to activate that 2 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma on line 46. This shows in the console of your browser in the developer tools as an error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Just add a comma at the end of that line:

```
"We are what we repeatedly do. excellence, then, is not an act but a habit.—Aristotle",
```

Comment: wow it worked. thanks a million Rob. you are amazing. It's not easy for me to catch these kinds of errors yet.